# Same record want to remove in sql

Tags: sql

My table structure like :
Table Structure

```
Customer_Name   Month   Year    Effective_Date  Value
  Sanjay         Jan    2018      01-Jan-18       10
  Sanjay         Feb    2018      01-Feb-18       11
  Sanjay         Mar    2018      01-Mar-18       11
  Sanjay         Apr    2018      01-Apr-18       13
  Sanjay         May    2018      01-May-18       15
  Sanjay         Jun    2018      01-Jun-18       15
  Sanjay         Jul    2018      01-Jul-18       15
  Sanjay         Aug    2018      01-Aug-18       16
  Sanjay         Sep    2018      01-Sep-18       14
```

I want output like this:

```
Customer_Name   Month   Year    Effective_Date  Value
  Sanjay         Jan    2018      01-Jan-18       10
  Sanjay         Feb    2018      01-Feb-18       11
  Sanjay         Apr    2018      01-Apr-18       13
  Sanjay         May    2018      01-May-18       15
  Sanjay         Aug    2018      01-Aug-18       16
  Sanjay         Sep    2018      01-Sep-18       14
```

**Logic: If simultaneous rows value will same then only first row will come.**

I can do this using cursor. But I don't want to use cursor. Is there any other way to do do this?

Comment: Do not add tags for databases you do not use.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the output. What is the criteria to remove a row from the desired output?

Comment: logic updated in main question.

Comment: I suggest adding the tag for the DBMS you are *really* using back as well; as that's a really important piece of information we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check both scripts find same results :

```
SELECT   Customer_Name
        ,YEAR(MIN(Effective_date)) [Year]
        ,DATENAME(month,MIN(Effective_date)) [Month]
        ,MIN(Effective_date) Effective_date
        ,Value
FROM TableCustomer
GROUP BY Customer_Name
        ,Value



SELECT   T1.*
FROM TableCustomer T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Customer_Name,Value,MIN(Effective_date) Effective_date FROM TableCustomer GROUP BY Customer_Name,Value) T2  
        ON T1.Customer_Name = T2.Customer_Name 
        AND T1.Value = T2.Value 
        AND T1.Effective_date = T2.Effective_date
ORDER BY T1.Effective_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by using `ROW_NUMBER()` in following:

```
select Customer_Name, Month, Year, Effective_Date, Value
from (
    select 
        *,
        cast(Effective_Date as date) as sort_date, 
        row_number() over(partition by Value order by cast(Effective_Date as date)) as rn
    from #t
)x
where rn = 1
order by sort_date
```

Answer (score 0):

if `Effective_Date` is a `Date` data type:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename t 
WHERE 
t.Effective_Date = (
    SELECT MIN(tt.Effective_Date) FROM tablename tt 
    WHERE 
    tt.Customer_Name = t.Customer_Name AND
    tt.Month = t.Month AND
    tt.Year = t.Year AND
    tt.Value = t.Value
)
```

If the pattern is always like the above sample, you can omit:

```
tt.Month = t.Month AND
tt.Year = t.Year AND
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE as below,

```
WITH Customer_CTE(Effective_Date)
AS
(
    SELECT MIN(Effective_Date) AS Effective_Date
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY Value
)

SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Effective_Date IN (SELECT DISTINCT Effective_Date FROM Customer_CTE)
```